# Pattern to share data between objects in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have started a migration of a high energy physics algorithm written in FORTRAN to an object oriented approach in C++.  The FORTRAN code uses a lot of global variables all across a lot of functions.

I have simplified the global variables into a set of input variables, and a set of *invariants* (variables calculated once at the beginning of the algorithm and then used by all the functions).

Also, I have divided the full algorithm into three logical steps, represented by three different classes. So, in a very simple way, I have something like this:

```
double calculateFactor(double x, double y, double z)
{
    InvariantsTypeA invA();
    InvariantsTypeB invB();

    // they need x, y and z
    invA.CalculateValues();
    invB.CalculateValues();

    Step1 s1();
    Step2 s2();
    Step3 s3();

    // they need x, y, z, invA and invB
    return s1.Eval() + s2.Eval() + s3.Eval();
}
```

My problem is:

- for doing the calculations all the `InvariantsTypeX` and `StepX` objects need the input parameters (and these are not just three).
- the three objects `s1`, `s2` and `s3` need the data of the `invA` and `invB` objects.
- all the classes use several other classes through composition to do their job, and all those classes also need the input and the *invariants* (by example, `s1` has a member object `theta` of class `ThetaMatrix` that needs `x`, `z` and `invB` to get constructed).
- I cannot rewrite the algorithm to reduce the global values, because it follows several high energy physics formulas, and those formulas are just like that.

Is there a good pattern to share the input parameters and the *invariants* to all the objects used to calculate the result?

Should I use singletons? (but the `calculateFactor` function is evaluated around a million of times)

Or should I pass all the required data as arguments to the objects when they are created?(but if I do that then the data will be passed everywhere in every member object of every class, creating a mess)

Thanks.

Comment: "Should I use singletons?" NOOOOOOOOOOO! (Yelling in a very melodramatic way, in slow-motion :) )

Comment: To clarify what @John is saying: singletons are a useful tool but they are not the appropriate tool for this situation. I'm not entirely convinced you even need to use classes here, as this is very much the domain of functional programming, but it is not the worst possible solution to the problem.

Comment: Did the FORTRAN have "named COMMON blocks"?

Comment: The FORTRAN code is a mess, a lot of includes everywhere, no COMMON blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in C++ the most suitable solution, given your constraints and conditions, is represented by pointers. Many developers told you to use boost::shared_ptr. Well it is not necessary, although it provides a better performance especially when considering portability and robustness to system faults.

It is not necessary for you to bind to boost. It is true that they are not compiled and that now standardization processes will lead to c++ with boost directly integrated as a standard library, but if you do not want to use an external library you obviously can.

So let's go and try to solve your problem using just C++ and what it provides actually.

You'll probably have a main method and there, you told before, initialize all invariants elements... so you basically have constants and they can be every possible type. no need to make them constant if you want, however, in main you instantiate your invariant elements and point them for all those components requiring their usage. First in a separate file called "common_components.hpp" consider the following (I assume that you need some types for your invariant variables):

```
typedef struct {
   Type1 invariant_var1;
   Type2 invariant_var2;
   ...
   TypeN invariant_varN;
} InvariantType; // Contains the variables I need, it is a type, instantiating it will generate a set of global variables.
typedef InvariantType* InvariantPtr; // Will point to a set of invariants
```

In your "main.cpp" file you'll have:

```
#include "common_components.hpp"
// Functions declaration
int main(int, char**);
MyType1 CalculateValues1(InvariantPtr); /* Your functions have as imput param the pointer to globals */
MyType2 CalculateValues2(InvariantPtr); /* Your functions have as imput param the pointer to globals */
...
MyType3 CalculateValuesN(InvariantPtr); /* Your functions have as imput param the pointer to globals */
// Main implementation
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   InvariantType invariants = {
      value1,
      value2,
      ...
      valueN
   }; // Instantiating all invariants I need.
   InvariantPtr global = &invariants;
   // Now I have my variable global being a pointer to global.
   // Here I have to call the functions
   CalculateValue1(global);
   CalculateValue2(global);
   ...
   CalculateValueN(global);
}
```

If you have functions returning or using the global variable use the pointer to the struct modifying you methods' interface. By doing so all changes will be flooded to all using thoss variables.

Answer (score 2):

Why not passing the invariants as a function parameter or to the constructor of the class having the calculateFactor method ?

Also try to gather parameters together if you have too many params for a single function (for instance, instead of (x, y, z) pass a 3D point, you have then only 1 parameter instead of 3).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple template class to share data between objects in C++ and it is called shared_ptr. It is in the new STL and in boost.

If two objects both have a shared_ptr to the same object they get shared access to whatever data it holds.

In your particular case you probably don't want this but want a simple class that holds the data.

```
class FactorCalculator
{
   InvariantsType invA;
   InvariantsType invB;

public:
   FactorCalculator() // calculate the invariants once per calculator
   {
      invA.CalculateValues();
      invB.CalculateValues();
   }

   // call multiple times with different values of x, y, z
   double calculateFactor( double x, double y, double z ) /*const*/ 
   {
       // calculate using pre-calculated values in invA and invB
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> three logical steps, represented by three different classes

This may not have been the best approach.

A single class can have a large number of "global" variables, shared by all methods of the class.

What I've done when converting old codes (C or Fortran) to new OO structures is to try to create a single class which represents a more complete "thing".

In some case, well-structured FORTRAN would use "Named COMMON Blocks" to cluster things into meaningful groups.  This is a hint as to what the "thing" really was.

Also, FORTRAN will have lots of parallel arrays which aren't really separate things, they're separate attributes of a common thing.

```
DOUBLE X(200)
DOUBLE Y(200)
```

Is really a small class with two attributes that you would put into a collection.

Finally, you can easily create large classes with nothing but data, separate from the the class that contains the functions that do the work.  This is kind of creepy, but it allows you to finesse the common issue by translating a COMMON block into a class and simply passing an instance of that class to every function that uses the COMMON.

Comment: Indeed: if the algorithm is a three-step thing that needs all the same data, use one class. No need to seperate everything into oblivion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing each parameter individually, create another class to store them all and pass an instance of that class:

```
// Before
void f1(int a, int b, int c) {
    cout << a << b << c << endl;
}

// After
void f2(const HighEnergyParams& x) {
    cout << x.a << x.b << x.c << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am doing that, but I wanted to show the original problem to see if someone gives another solution.

Answer (score 0):

First point: globals aren't *nearly* as bad (in themselves) as many (most?) programmers claim. In fact, in themselves, they aren't really bad at all. They're primarily a symptom of other problems, primarily 1) logically separate pieces of code that have been unnecessarily intermixed, and 2) code that has unnecessary data dependencies.

In your case, it *sounds* like already eliminated (or at least minimized) the real problems (being invariants, not really variables eliminates one major source of problems all by itself). You've already stated that you can't eliminate the data dependencies, and you've apparently un-mingled the code to the point that you have at least two distinct sets of invariants. Without seeing the code, that may be coarser granularity than really needed, and maybe upon closer inspection, some of those dependencies can be eliminated completely.

If you can reduce or eliminate the dependencies, that's a worthwhile pursuit -- but eliminating the globals, in itself, is rarely worthwhile or useful. In fact, I'd say within the last decade or so, I've seen fewer problems caused by globals, than by people who didn't really understand their problems attempting to eliminate what were (or should have been) perfectly fine as globals.

Given that they are intended to be invariant, what you probably *should* do is enforce that explicitly. For example, have a factory class (or function) that creates an invariant class. The invariant class makes the factory its friend, but that's the *only* way members of the invariant class can change. The factory class, in turn, has (for example) a static `bool`, and executes an `assert` if you attempt to run it more than once. This gives (a reasonable level of) assurance that the invariants really are invariant (yes, a `reinterpret_cast` will let you modify the data anyway, but not by accident).

The one real question I'd have is whether there's a real point in separating your invariants into two "chunks" if all the calculations really depend on both. If there's a clear, logical separation between the two, that's great (even if they do get used together). If you have what's logically a single block of data, however, trying to break it into pieces may be counterproductive.

Bottom line: globals are (at worst) a symptom, not a disease. Insisting that you're *going* to get the patient's temperature down to 98.6 degrees may be counterproductive -- especially if the patient is an animal whose normal body temperature is actually 102 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

uhm. Cpp is not necessarily object oriented. It is the GTA of programming! You are free to be a Object obscessed freak, a relax C programmer, a functional programmer, what ever; a mix martial artist.

My point, if Global variables worked in your fortran compile, just copy and paste to Cpp. No need to avoid global variables. It follows the principle of, dont touch legacy code.

Lets understand why global variables may cause problem. As you know, variables is the programs`s state and state is the soul of the program. Bad or invalid state causes runtime and logic errors. The problem with global variables/ global state, is that any part of our code has access to it; thus in case of invalid state, their are many bad guys or culprits to consider, meaning functions and operators. However this is only applicable if you really used so many functions on your global variable. I mean you are the only one working on your lonely program. Global variables are only a real problem if you are doing a team project. In that case many people have access to it, writing different functions that may or may not be accessing that variable.